# Extracting data from Salesforce using SystemModStamp

Tags: data, increment

I am looking at pulling data from Salesforce incrementally using the "systemmodstamp" field into a "data lake". The plan is to use the max(systemmodstamp) in the datalake, as the filter for the next incremental load.

Run 1: Salesforce object data where systemmodstamp > 2001-01-01. (initial run)

Run 2: Salesforce object data where systemmodstamp > max(systemmodstamp) for the object in the datalake.

Run 3: Salesforce object data where systemmodstamp > max(systemmodstamp) for the object in the datalake.

I had 2 questions:

1. Can I use "greater than" or should I use "greater than equal to"? i.e. is it possible for records with the same systemmodstamp to not be written to Salesforce all at the same time? If it is possible that records with the same systemmodstamp could be written over a short period of time, then, I should use "greater than equal to".
2. Should I offset the max(systemmodstamp) I use as my filter criteria? i.e. is it possible for records with systemmodstamp that is earlier than max(systemmodstamp) to have not been updated in Salesforce and so I need to use a buffer to be sure to pull data that has not been written yet into salesforce in my run 2. This seems an unlikely scenario, as then it would be very hard to pull data into a separate system using systemmodstamp, but I wanted to ask this question, as I wasnt sure about what kind of guarantees Salesforce system provides around the data that is written to its system.

I believe that the systemmodstamp is written at the end of transactions, even those involving a lot of records. So, if I see one record with a systemmodstamp, then I should see all records with the same systemmodstamp. So, even scenario 1 should not be a concern as all records with the systemmodstamp should have been completely written to Salesforce and I shouldnt have to worry about partial records.

Comment: Take a look at Change Data Capture and/or low-level replication APIs, they do this for you. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_guidelines_datareplication.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For data mirroring, don't use SOQL if you can help it. The [replication API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/calls_for_data_replication.htm) methods, getUpdated and getDeleted, will provide a full list of records that have been modified in the specified time frame, and also provides a time for the next API call; in other words, it will tell you the time stamp for the latest committed record. This API is also available in REST.